# Windows 8.1 DNS Issues

Tags: windows, networking, google-chrome, dns, remote-desktop

I'm currently having DNS issues on my Windows 8.1 Desktop that happens only on my desktop.

When I first boot up, if I try to browse to or ping any website via an internet browser or command prompt (respectively) it returns nothing what-so-ever, Chrome just brings back the NO DNS PROBE error and command prompt says it cannot find the host.

If I log in to my server via RDP (Server is on the same network on a static IP) then I can ping websites and browse to websites with no issue, the reason I know it is DNS based is because if I type Google's IP address in to my desktops browser address bar then it directs to Google just fine.

I have tried both Static & Dynamic DNS', I have released, renewed and flushed in command prompt, I have done 'winsock reset', I have also tried the set dns command via netsh. I have also scanned my machine for Rootkits & Malware with TDSSKiller, Malwarebytes & Rogue Killer, I have analyzed all processes with HijackThis & Process Hacker running to see if there is anything malicious and the computer seems to be completely clean.

Everything above either works during that 'session' until I restart the machine which breaks it again, or it just doesn't work at all. This DNS issue has started only since last week and I've seen various posts or threads which have the same issues on Windows 8.1 so I'm wondering if this is based with Windows 8.1 in general?

Is there anything I can do to fix this issue and stop it from happening at random times, mainly being on startup and randomly throughout my day of browsing or working?

--Update--

This isn't a Network card issue because it works perfectly fine in Safe Mode with Networking.

Comment: What DNS service are you using specifically?  This problem likely has nothing to do with `Windows 8.1` since this particular aspect of Windows has not changed in 15 years.

Comment: Statically I've used OpenDNS, GoogleDNS & dynamically I've used my ISP' DNS.

I also set up OpenDNS Statically on my router but that has made no difference on my desktop either. I have phoned my ISP to see if the issue was on their end, but after the phone call I checked other machines on the network which all work fine.

Comment: What security software do you have installed and does your *hosts* file only contain the typical default single entry?

Comment: I'm using standard Microsoft Security Essentials with Malwarebytes Anti-Malware (Licensed) and other various cleaning tools such as CCleaner and what not. The hosts file has some custom content in it but everything is and has been commented out for quite some time.

It isn't a hosts file issue anyway because I can access the websites via IP address; just not by domain names, domain names work just fine once I do flushdns or netsh winsock reset.

Comment: Do you have the capability to use an entirely different network adapter then you normally do on the problem computer?

Comment: I don't currently have another network adapter to use on the computer, I'll have to order one on Thursday and see if that's an issue. I recently received an amplifier and Digital-Analog convert which I noticed there seemed to be issues with the optical connection on the machine because there was a constant crackling coming from the audio source which worked fine on my T.V. After I installed the amp I picked up a sound card which I installed and hooked the optical up to, now I don't know exactly which part caused these issues but ever since that day I've had DNS issues intermittently.

Comment: In fact, something that tells me it's not a network adapter issue is the fact that everything works perfectly fine in Safe Mode with Networking.

Comment: You made no mention of that fact until just now.

Comment: Yeah I know, I posted this article when I was away from the machine and it slipped my mind, my apologies.

I just finished a scan with Avast free and that reported nothing either.